# C# Windows Service Import C++ dll Crash with Event ID: 1000 clr.dll

Tags: c#, c++, crash, windows-services, clr

I have a Windows service which imports a C++ dll. If I do pressure test, this Windows service will directly crashed with Event ID: 1000 showed module clr.dll but didn't log any exception. Event message as below:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-26T08:22:52.027599500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>5246</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Server.exe</Data>
    <Data>5.1.0.1</Data>
    <Data>5f8d0a4f</Data>
    <Data>clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.7.3680.0</Data>
    <Data>5f233da8</Data>
    <Data>c0000409</Data>
    <Data>0056aa27</Data>
    <Data>1fc4</Data>
    <Data>01d6ab1690751cd9</Data>
    <Data>Server.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>0772888d-b659-483c-b80b-d7b4de714636</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have tried some ways:

1. Windows Update
2. My C# project app.config add

```
    <configuration>
       <runtime>
          <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
       </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

and the function which use C++ dll add

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
```

3. All code use C++ dll are all added try catch, but Windows service still crashed without log any exception.

Windows environment is Windows Server 2016 64bit.
C++ dll is x86 thus I use x86 CPU - debug to build the project. I suspect the reason of crash caused by C++ dll but can't prove it.

Comment: "ANY" is a bad CPU choice when you have a C++ DLL. You must choose the CPU model (32/64) that matches the C++ code.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention that I have tested with CPU model x86 and met the same situation that Windows service also crashed.

Comment: The DLL could be 64 bits, in which case both "ANY" and "x86" are wrong and can cause crashes.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry for that I didn't describe clearly. I have confirmed that C++ dll is x86, thus built with x86 to test again, it's still in vain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simple solution is to *attach* the debugger to the service. You'll need to start Visual Studio as Administrator probably, because the service likely runs under a non-interactive login.

The "CorruptedState" not-solutions are a throwback to `IsBadReadPtr` , another unreliable and flaky method that Microsoft invented in the past. While debugging, the debugger is the better solution. Once released to customers, neither approach is guaranteed to catch the problem.

Comment: Could you advice any debugger tools? Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio will work just fine in 99% of the cases.